# Unfreeze super glue stuck in bottle nozzle

Tags: storage

I have a super glue bottle. The glue inside it is fine, but it has frozen in the nozzle part, that makes it useless.

How to fix this ?

Thanks

Comment: What does it exactly look like? Could you add a picture?

Comment: Surely more to the point is how to stop the glue setting in the first place.

Comment: That's not always possible, depending on the bottle design.

Comment: We used to put a nail in the nozzle to stop it from glocking @Chenmunka

Comment: @Hobbes - see my answer; putting it in the freezer stops it setting... though how practical a solution that is, idk :/

Answer (score 4):

You can drill it out using e.g. a cordless drill with variable speed, or a pin vise. I use a 1.5 mm drill bit.

Pin vise: 
[image: Pin vise]

Make sure not to put pressure on the glue bottle during drilling, or the glue will come gushing out. 
Clean the drill bit immediately after use to prevent the glue from drying on the bit. If you do get dried glue on the drill bit, you can scrape it off with a knife.

Comment: You can also avoid glue from setting on the drill bit with acetone. Even if it hardens on the drill, acetone will still remove the glue.

Answer (score 2):

My usual technique is to use squeeze the nozzle with a pliers a few times to loosen the dried glue, then have a good poke around with needle or pin.

Comment: This has the added benefit of not letting the Krazy glue spatter or on other things or dripping when you pull pins and drills out of the opening. It also leaves the opening small enough to make tiny drops where wanted.

Comment: Absolutely the best answer, would upvote 10 times if I could. It takes under 30 seconds and requires no specialized tools.

Answer (score 1):

Part marked as 'citation needed' however I just discovered this on Wikipedia doing a totally unrelated search. Three potential workarounds, as prevention rather than cure...

> The reaction with moisture can cause a container of glue which has been opened and resealed to become unusable more quickly than if never opened.
>
> To minimise this reduction in shelf life cyanoacrylate, once opened, can be stored in an airtight container with a package of silica gel desiccant.
>
> Another technique is to insert a hypodermic needle into the opening of a tube. After using the glue, residual glue soon clogs the needle, keeping moisture out. The clog is removed by heating the needle (e.g. with a lighter) before use.[citation needed].
>
> The polymerisation is also temperature-dependant: storage at zero degrees or below stops it, so keeping it in the freezer is also effective.

Source: [Wikipedia : Cyanoacrylate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyanoacrylate)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the size of the head opening, i usually find a sharp stanley knife will allow you to cut out the solid glue enough so you can use the contents again.

But yea if its really bad, get your smallest drill bit out, sometimes even a mini screwdriver will do the trick and is quicker then setting up a drill.

Comment: The knife has a drawback: when you cut off the top of the nozzle, the remaining part will have a bigger opening. This makes applying a small amount of glue more difficult.

Comment: You often dont need to cut it off. Use the very sharp tip to pierce the glue in a circular motion sometimes is a viable option. But this depends on the size of the bottle / existing opening / how long the glue has been hard for.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a pin or similar-sized pointy object and heat it up (ideally with a lighter) and push the hot tip through the dried glue/nozzle. This has helped me on more than one occasion with minimal damage and spills.

Answer (score 0):

If the glue is based on something called cyanoacrylate (ie crazy glue). To dissolve or loosen use acetone. Acetone is commonly used in nail polishes. You can get the clear kind and dip the end of the device pictured Hobbes post. Then you're good to go...

Answer (score 0):

According to the package instructions, nail polish remover can be used to remove Krazy glue residue.

In my experience, once open, the Krazy glue won't last very long for a second application. I have been getting "single application" sizes of the stuff.